# How to remove active class in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

After adding the active class to an element.

```
 ng-class="{active: $index == selected}"
```

How can remove it by some button click in another function scope.

Comment: By setting $scope.selected to a value that is not equal to $index.

Answer (score 0):

add another variable for tracking click `buttonClicked`

```
ng-class="{active: (($index == selected) && !buttonClicked)}"

<button ng-click="buttonClicked=true">Disable class</button>
```

as per the comment of Satpal you can achieve the same result by setting `$scope.selected = -1`

```
ng-class="{active: $index == selected}"
<button ng-click="selected=-1">Disable class</button>
```

Comment: Why not just reset `selected ` i.e. `$scope.selected = -1`